# The best way to insert large amount of messages into TorqueBox message queue

Tags: jruby, messaging, hornetq, torquebox

what's the fastest way to push millions of messages into HornetQ? I have these both approaches:

1.) My current code, reuses one session for all messages, ca. 2.200 messages per second

```
time = Benchmark.realtime do
  queue.with_session(:tx => false) do |session| 
    1_000_000.times do
      payload = Array.new(32){rand(36).to_s(36)}.join
      session.publish(queue, payload, queue.normalize_options(:persistent => false))
    end
  end
end
puts "Time elapsed #{time} seconds ..."
```

2.) The optimized way, but it hangs after the first 30k messages, til then 9.000 messages per second

```
time = Benchmark.realtime do
  queue.with_session(:tx => false) do |session|
    options = queue.normalize_options(:persistent => false)
    producer = session.instance_variable_get('@jms_session').create_producer(session.java_destination(queue))
    1_000_000.times do
      payload = Array.new(32){rand(36).to_s(36)}.join
      message = TorqueBox::Messaging::Message.new(session.instance_variable_get('@jms_session'), payload, options[:encoding])

      message.populate_message_headers(options)
      message.populate_message_properties(options[:properties])

      producer.disable_message_id = true
      producer.disable_message_timestamp = true

      producer.send( message.jms_message,
        options.fetch(:delivery_mode, producer.delivery_mode),
        options.fetch(:priority, producer.priority),
        options.fetch(:ttl, producer.time_to_live)
      )
    end
  end
end
puts "Time elapsed #{time} seconds …"
```

The question is, why does the second snippet hang after the 30k? What would you recommend for massive inserts into HornetQ?

Regards,
Chris

Comment: I use RabbitMQ with Torquebox due to https://issues.jboss.org/browse/TORQUE-1174 and https://issues.jboss.org/browse/TORQUE-1175, being able to use non-blocking IO with the messaging system is really helpful. Also, you have access to all the queueing features when outside JBoss which is really helpful too. Both aspects would be helpful in your case.